# Cast a class to interface within spring

Tags: java, spring, osgi, confluence

I am hitting a wall with a ClassCastException, wondering what I do wrong.
I have an API interface

```
public interface MyService{
    method A()
    method B()
}
```

implemented by a class

```
public class ServiceImpl implements MyService{
     //methods here
}
```

extended by another:

```
@Component("service")
public class ExtendedServiceImpl extends ServiceImpl
{
    //overriden methods
}
```

and in spring-components.xml

```
<osgi:service ref="service"
    interface="my.package.api.MyService" />
```

Now in another plugin I would like to have access to the service so I am invoking

```
ServiceReference s_reference = context.getServiceReference(MyService.class.getName());
MyService s=(MyService)context.getService(s_reference);
```

which throws ClassCastException. I can see by console printing s_reference is of type ExtendedServiceImpl which I don't have reference in that plugin.

**Edit:**
Trimmed manifest of client:

```
Export-Service: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.StrategyRegistrationProvider
Import-Package: com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.overriden;version="1.0.469", com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.service;version="1.0.469"
```

Trimmed manifest of service

```
Bnd-LastModified: 1412434741719
Bundle-ClassPath: .,META-INF/lib/aspectjweaver-1.8.2.jar,META-INF/lib/
 atlassian-cache-compat-1.0.1.jar,META-INF/lib/atlassian-pocketknife-d
 ynamic-modules-0.20.jar,META-INF/lib/confluence-questions-api-1.0.469
 .jar,META-INF/lib/jooq-3.3.1.jar,META-INF/lib/jsp-api-2.0.jar
Bundle-Description: Confluence Questions
Bundle-DocURL: http://www.atlassian.com/
Bundle-License: http://www.atlassian.com/end-user-agreement/
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Confluence Questions Plugin
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.confluence-quest
 ions
Bundle-Vendor: Atlassian
Bundle-Version: 1.0.469
Export-Package: 

com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.model,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.overriden.admin,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.overriden;uses:="com.atlassian.bandana,
com.atlassian.confluence.setup.bandana,
com.atlassian.spring.container,com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.service,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.service,
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.model,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.repository,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.service.mapper,
com.atlassian.event.api,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.permission,
com.atlassian.confluence.user,
com.atlassian.sal.api.message,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.dto,
org.springframework.stereotype,
com.atlassian.user,
com.atlassian.hibernate,
com.atlassian.bonnie.analyzer,
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.search.api";version="1.0.469",
com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.service
```

At start i thought there was some inheritance problem thus I used sample classes. 
The MyService inteface lays at com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.service
The ServiceImpl lays at com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.service
The ExtendedServiceImpl lays at com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.overriden

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Please also post the full stacktrace.

Comment: `getServiceReference(Service.class.getName());`, what `Service` do you use here? [This one](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html)?

Comment: Maybe that should be MyService.class instead of Service.class?

Comment: @John that was my thought.

Comment: So, isn't that fix for your problem?

Comment: No still getting java.lang.ClassCastException: ExtendedServiceImpl cannot be cast to MyService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct. The problem is about managing you package imports / exports.

This typically happens when there are two instances of the class MyService.class. Take a look into the bundle offering the service as well as the one using the service.

If you have no separate API bundle then the bundle offering the service should contain the MyService.class and export the package it is in. The bundle using the service should NOT contain the MyService.class and import the package it is in.

Also make sure that the packages of MyService.class is in a separate package from the impl and the using class - I think it should be the case already as your package name sounds like an API package name.

Comment: I remember reading somewhere about this two instances problem you describe. MyService, ServiceImpl and ExtendedServiceImpl are under same project whilst I am trying to grab the service from another project. Will you be kind enough to point on documentation regarding these package imports/exports you mention?

Comment: I assume you use the maven bundle plugin to create the bundles. In this case see the documentation of the maven bundle plugin at: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html 

Also you should check the Manifest of the created jar file for your service and client. If you want you can post the Manifest contents here and I take a look.

Comment: I did a few changes on the pom import/export as you pointed (many thanks btw), and now getting Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class. I am editing original question to include manifests

Comment: I think you still have the classloading problem. The client Manifest does not have an import of com.atlassian.confluence.plugins.questions.api.service. The service Manifest looks ok. Also make sure the service interface is not inside the client jar. It should only have the Import-Package.